# Tableview: Name is selected, best way to store the ID (not name) in a variable?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am new to swift and programming in general. I have a tableview with a dynamic cell, where each cell displays a name from my array `["John","Steve","Matt"]`

I am able to see which row is selected, by doing `Print(IndexPath.item)` in `didSelectRowAt`

Each of these names has an ID number (1,2,3) that I have not implemented yet, but I want to store the ID number of the selected row in a variable (`var idSelected`)

What would be the best way to do this?

I guess I could do one big "if statement", but I will have hundreds of names, so this is not efficient. I was thinking of somehow using a Struct, to store the ID of the corresponding name selected, but wanted some guidance

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps:

```
//1. Create a structure to hold the data
struct Person{
    let name : String
    let id : String

    init(name: String, id: String){
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //2. Create a datasource array
    let datasource : [Person] = [Person(name: "Name1", id: "111"),
                                 Person(name: "Name2", id: "222"),
                                 Person(name: "Name3", id: "333"),
                                 Person(name: "Name4", id: "444"),
                                   ]

    var personIDArray: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

        //3. Extract the Person's id from Array
        let person = datasource[indexPath.row]

        //4. Add id to the array
        personIDArray.append(person.id)
    }
}
```

Comment: `init(name: String, id: String)` this initialiser is redundant when using structures.

Comment: you can simplify your array declaration  `let datasource = [("Name1","111"), ("Name2", "222"), ("Name3", "333"),("Name4", id: "444")].map(Person.init)`

Answer (score 0):

A more scalable solution is, to start designing in object oriented way, so that in future if you have more details of the person is required to store, you can add that to the struct.

```
    struct Person {
        let name: String
        let ID: Int
    }
```

Then define `persons` array as a property.

```
    var persons = [Person]()
```

Whenever you get the values populate the array, for example from `ViewDidLoad()`.

```
    // populate persons
    // assuming the personsData = [(id: name), (id: name), ....]
    for (key, value) in personsData {
        persons.append(Person(name: value, id: key))
    }
```

Inside the `cellForRowAt`, you can get the individual person object and pick up your necessary name and id from it.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let person = persons[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel.text = person.name
    }
```

Same you can take up the `person.id` from `didSelectRowAt`

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let person = persons[indexPath.row]
            // doSomething with `person.id`
        }
```